# TStream to TStringList fails for unicode Delphi

Tags: delphi, unicode, stream, delphi-7, delphi-xe

As shown in `Test2` of the following code, a TStringList is converted to a TStream and then the TStream is converted back to a TStringList. However, in Delphi 7 `Test2` gives the same as `Test1`. In unicode Delphi, `Test2` does not give correct result. Could you help to suggest what is wrong ?

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}

uses
  Classes, SysUtils;

// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/732666
// Converting TMemoryStream to String in Delphi 2009
function MemoryStreamToString(M: TMemoryStream): string;
begin
  SetString(Result, PChar(M.Memory), M.Size div SizeOf(Char));
end;

procedure Test1;
var
  SrcList: TStrings;
  S: String;
  AStream: TStream;
begin
  SrcList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    with SrcList do
    begin
      Add('aa');
      Add('bb');
      Add('cc');
    end;

    S := SrcList.Text;

    AStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      // AStream.Write(S[1], Length(S));
      // AStream.Write(S[1], Length(S) * SizeOf(Char));
      AStream.Write(Pointer(S)^, Length(S) * SizeOf(Char));

      WriteLn(MemoryStreamToString(TMemoryStream(AStream)));
    finally
      AStream.Free;
    end;
  finally
    SrcList.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure Test2;
var
  SrcList: TStrings;
  S: String;
  AStream: TStream;
  DestList: TStringList;
  I: Integer;
begin
  SrcList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    with SrcList do
    begin
      Add('aa');
      Add('bb');
      Add('cc');
    end;

    S := SrcList.Text;

    AStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      // AStream.Write(S[1], Length(S));
      // AStream.Write(S[1], Length(S) * SizeOf(Char));
      AStream.Write(Pointer(S)^, Length(S) * SizeOf(Char));

      DestList := TStringList.Create;
      try
        AStream.Position := 0;
        DestList.LoadFromStream(AStream);

        WriteLn(DestList.Text);
      finally
        DestList.Free;
      end;
    finally
      AStream.Free;
    end;
  finally
    SrcList.Free;
  end;
end;

begin
  try
    Test1;
    Test2;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      WriteLn(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: Aside: replace `DestList := nil;
  try
    DestList := TStringList.Create;` with `DestList := TStringList.Create; try`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Do you mean there will be no exception in the constructor ? When there can be exception in the constructore, it seems that the call to Create should reside in the try-finally. Could you help to comment ? :p

Comment: If there is an exception raised in the constructor then the destructor will be called, and the assignment to `DestList` will not occur. The correct idiom is as per my comment

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Without `DestList := nil` before `try-finally`, if exception is raised in the constructor and then the destructor is called, `DestList.Free` in the `finally` part will fail. Could you help to comment ? :D

Comment: Look very closely at the code in my comment. If the constructor raises then `DestList` is indeed never assigned a value. But also, this happens before the `try` and so the `finally` block is not executed. Have a good look around the RTL/VCL source and see which form prevails.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Could you help to check whether it is correct now ? :D Thank you very much for your time to help !

Comment: Yes, that is spot on

Comment: @DavidHeffernan (Now `Readln` also stays at a correct place! :D) Thank you very much again !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Test1` writes the raw `String` data as-is into the `TMemoryStream` and then reads it back as-is into a `String`, thus everything matches correctly in all versions of Delphi.  `Test2` works in Delphi 2007 and earlier for a similar reason.

`Test2` fails in Delphi 2009 and later because you are not taking into account that `TStrings.LoadFrom...()` (and `TStrings.SaveTo...()`) is `TEncoding`-aware in those versions of Delphi.  You are writing UTF-16 encoded data into the `TMemoryStream` without a BOM in front, and then you are not telling `LoadFromStream()` that the stream is UTF-16 encoded.  It tries to locate a BOM, and when it does not find one, it loads the stream using `TEncoding.Default` (aka 8bit Ansi) instead (for backwards compatibility with legacy code).

So, in this example, you need to specify the proper encoding of the stream data when loading it in Delphi 2009 and later:

```
DestList.LoadFromStream(AStream, TEncoding.Unicode);
```

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer very much !